# Could the “ていない” in “絶対無理って言ってない？” be interpreted as past?

Tags: tense

“絶対無理って言ってない？” from context I would translate it as “didn’t you say it was impossible?”, but I just can’t wrap my head around the grammar. How would “って言ってなかった？” or “って言わなかった？” change the meaning?

Comment: Can't you just use the present progressive, "Aren't you saying it's impossible?" Doesn't it make sense in the context?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context, the ～ている form can be similar in function to the present progressive in English, like *"is `[VERB]`ing"*, or it can be considered as broadly analogous to the nuance in English construction *"have `[VERB]`ed"*.

Looking at this *"have `[VERB]`ed"* sense, compare the following translations of your example phrases:

- って言っていない → *haven't said / told* (at the "present" relative to the time of the statement)
- って言ってなかった → *hadn't said / told* (at some point in the past; could imply that the speaker may have said or told the other person after that point)
- って言わなかった → *didn't say / tell* (at some point in the past; no implication about later action)

The translations above are not guaranteed to apply to all contexts, and are intended to give you a sense for the differences in nuance as related to tense, and the time of the statement relative to the time of the action.